# Como conseguir el mismo formato de salida de subprocess.stdout que el de shell

Tags: python

estoy intentando crear una consola mysql, y quisiera que los resultados fueran iguales  a los de su consola.
Cuando ejecuto

```
sql = "mysql -u root -ppass Pruebas -e 'SELECT * FROM 'datos_usuarios''"

subprocess.run(sql, shell=True)
```

Obtengo

```
+----+---------+------------+-----------+
| Id | Nombre  | Apellido   | Direccion |
+----+---------+------------+-----------+
|  1 | Ana     | López      | Gran Vía  |
|  3 | Sandra  | Martín     | Sagasta   |
|  4 | Juan    | Gómez      | ejemplo4  |
|  6 | Sara    | Fernández  | ejemplo3  |
|  8 | Sandra  | Martínez   | ejem5     |
|  9 | María   | Fernández  | ejem6     |
| 12 | María   | López      | ejemplo10 |
+----+---------+------------+-----------+
```

Y este es el formato que me gustaria tener al capturarla con stdout

```
shellSQL = subprocess.run(sql, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)

print(shellSQL.stdout)
```

Pero obtengo esto

```
Id      Nombre  Apellido        Direccion
1       Ana     López   Gran Vía
3       Sandra  Martín  Sagasta
4       Juan    Gómez   ejemplo4
6       Sara    Fernández       ejemplo3
8       Sandra  Martínez        ejem5
9       María   Fernández       ejem6
12      María   López   ejemplo10
```

Como puedo lograrlo?

Gracias

Comment: has probado con crear una variable cache para el ´stdout´?, y mover el ´stdout´ de el primer proceso a esa variable? NOTA: si haces eso la variable seria de typo `bytes`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso no es cosa de Python, sino de mysql que adapta su salida al entorno de ejecución. Cuando detecta que la salida estándar está redirigida (como es el caso de `subprocess.run()`) abandona el formato tabla en favor de uno delimitado por tabuladores.

Puedes forzar a que use el formato tabla ascii añadiendo la opción `--table` al comando `mysql`.

(Referencia: [Documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-output-table-format.html))